# MySQL SyntaxErrorException

Tags: java, mysql

public static LoginBean logIn(String userName)throws Exception{

```
    String query="select user_name, password from login where user_name="+userName;
    System.out.println(query);

    Statement st=null;
    ResultSet result=null;
    LoginBean bean=new LoginBean();
    try{
        st=con.createStatement();
        result=st.executeQuery(query);

        while(result.next()){

            bean.setUserName(result.getString("user_name"));
            bean.setPassword(result.getString("password"));
        }
        return bean;
    }
    finally
    {
        if(result!=null)
        {
            result.close();
        }
        if(st!=null)
        {
            st.close();
        }            
    }
}
```

I am executing this method but its giving me the error i.e. `com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'admin' in 'where clause'` I have checked the syntax but could not find the error.

Comment: *"I have checked the syntax"* - Have you?  Can you include in the question the actual runtime value of the SQL query you're trying to execute?  Telling us that you've checked it and you think it's right isn't the same thing as showing it to us so *we* can check it.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing quotes around the user name 'admin', which makes `mySQL` think you are referring to a column name instead of a value.

That said, you should use `PreparedStatement`:

```
String query="select user_name, password from login where user_name=?";
System.out.println(query);

PreparedStatement st=null;
ResultSet result=null;
LoginBean bean=new LoginBean();
try{
    st=con.prepareStatement(query);
    st.setString(1,userName);
    result=st.executeQuery();
    ...
```

Comment: I wish we could eradicate every tutorial and code snippet that doesn't use a `PreparedStatement`.

Comment: what is the method setString(1, userName); for ??

Comment: @TaimoorKhan It replaces the `?` in the SQL string with the value stored in the `userName` variable.